# Power of martingales is a submartingales

Tags: probability, probability-theory, martingales

Let $X := \{X_n\}_{n=0}^\infty$ be a martingales. Let $1 \leq s < \infty$, with $||X||_s < \infty$.

Prove that $Y := \{ |X_n|^s \}_{n=0}^\infty$ is a sub-martingales

I have tried using the definition of martingales with the conditional mean, but i cannot arrive at the solution

Comment: For $\varphi:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ a convex function, $(\varphi(X_n))_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is a submartingale. Since $x\mapsto\vert x\vert^s$ is convex, $(\vert X_n\vert^s)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is a submartingale.

Comment: How would you demonstrate that?

Answer (score 1):

It is a direct consequence of Jensen's inequality for conditional expectations: let $X$ be an integrable real valued random variable, $\varphi:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ be a convex function such that $\varphi(X)$ is integrable and $\mathcal G$ be a $\sigma$-algebra. Then almost surely,
$$
\varphi(\mathbb E[X\vert\mathcal G])\le\mathbb E[\varphi(X)\vert\mathcal G].
$$

So in your case, since $x\mapsto\vert x\vert^s$ is convex, Jensen's inequality for conditional expectation writes for all $n\in\mathbb N$,
$$
Y_n=\vert X_n\vert^s=\vert\mathbb E[X_{n+1}\vert X_n]\vert^s\le\mathbb E[\vert X_{n+1}\vert^s\vert X_n]=\mathbb E[Y_{n+1}\vert X_n].
$$

Since $Y_n=\vert X_n\vert^s$, we have $\sigma(Y_n)\subset\sigma(X_n)$ so
$$
\mathbb E[Y_{n+1}\vert Y_n]=\mathbb E[\mathbb E[Y_{n+1}\vert X_n]\vert Y_n]\ge\mathbb E[Y_n\vert Y_n]=Y_n,
$$
hence $(Y_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is a submartingale. Notice that this would have still held true if $(X_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ was only a submartingale.